# Approximate values of $\operatorname{E}[\sqrt X]$ and $\operatorname{Var}[\sqrt X]$ for $X$ Poisson distributed with parameter $\lambda\to\infty$

Tags: taylor-expansion, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

> Assume that $X$ has a Poisson distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$. If $Y = \sqrt X$, using moment-generating functions or otherwise, show that $$\operatorname{E}[Y] \approx \sqrt\lambda - \frac 1 {8 \sqrt\lambda}$$ and $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] \approx \frac14$$

A suggestion is to use MGFs but I've got no idea how to go from there as I keep getting jammed.

Comment: In what sense are you using "show" here? Since you don't specify the order or accuracy of the approximation, we can provide heuristic arguments for it, but there's nothing to "show" in a formal sense.

Comment: I don't have a clue sorry, I didn't write the question but you're trying to show that E[X] and Var[X] can be approximated to those values

Comment: If you didn't write the question, you should clearly mark it as a quote (e.g. using markdown's blockquote feature).

Comment: Fixed that up sorry

Comment: I think you misunderstood the blockquote mechanism. It's a single `>` at the beginning of the paragraph. I fixed it.

Comment: No worries thanks for that, I probably should have read that up before I posted

Comment: Please try a less calamitous (and even, wrong) title next time.

Comment: No problem I'll think of a more realistic title next time I post, was in a hurry to get this up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an exercise in the [delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method). Since $dY/dX=1/(2\sqrt{X})$, $\operatorname{Var}Y\approx\frac{\lambda}{(2\sqrt{\lambda})^2}=\frac{1}{4}$. Then $E(Y)=\sqrt{\lambda}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4\lambda}}$ gives the desired result.

Comment: You're a legend cheers J.G. what formula did you use to find E[X]?

Comment: @JamesSilber The Poisson distribution has mean & variance both equal to $\lambda$.

Comment: I know that I meant E[Y] sorry, because why do you multiply sqrt(lambda) by sqrt(1-1/4*lambda)

Comment: Well, $E^2Y=E(Y^2)-\operatorname{Var}Y\approx\lambda-\frac{1}{4}$, which we square-root by first taking out the factor of $\lambda$.

Comment: Got it thanks you're a life saver